# How can I execute two stored procedure at a time in sql

Tags: sql

I have two stored procedures `input_data` and `Processing_data`. The `input_data` sends data to the `Processing_data` and it will send back another id to the `input_data`. So I need to run both the stored procedure at a same time? How can I do this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... and also: **how** are you sending data back and forth between those two procedures?

Comment: Why dont you do it both of this in single procedure??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to know the DB system to answer this. You call from input_data procedure the processing_data procedure, which will do something and then return the values back to input_data, right?

Here's one example, but the actual implementation *will* depend on what system you're using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE input_data AS
   DECLARE @return_val INT
   EXEC  @return_val = processing_data(some_other_value)
   PRINT 'Done'
```

Comment: That syntax wouldn't work with SQL Server where the OUT parameters should be passed to the stored procedure as OUT arguments.

Comment: yes, like I said it's just an example as there are differences. For working code used DB product would need to be known.